# mdframed environment not breaking over pages

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I apologise in advance because I cannot provide an MWE.

I am writing a book with a custom (Springer) format and I wish to use `mdframed` to provide an example environment. I adapted an example from the documentation and came up with this as a first draft:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{exampl}[section]
\newenvironment{exampl}[1][]{%
 \stepcounter{exampl}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=black!10]
        {\strut Example~\thesection .\theexampl};},nobreak=false}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
     frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=black!10]
        {\strut Example~\thesection .\theexampl:~#1};},nobreak=false}%
   }%
   \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=black!10,nobreak=false,%
             linewidth=2pt,topline=true,backgroundcolor=black!05,%
             frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax}
   \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
   }{\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{exampl}[Lorem ipsum]
   \blindtext

   \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & Table\\
   \end{tabular}

   \Blindtext
\end{exampl}

\end{document}
```

In the MWE provided, the `exampl` works fine and uses appropriate page-breaks. However, in the context of the source of the book I'm working on, the same environment will not break.

As per the MWE above, I tried explicitly adding `nobreak=false` everywhere to try force the page-break, but to to avail.

I've tried debugging it and working back towards an MWE, but to no avail. I believe it might be something in the custom book template that's causing the problem.

---

I know that my problem might not be reproducible and thus is not ideal for this site, but I was hoping someone might be able to offer some common reasons as to why an `mdframed` environment won't break across pages. I'm hoping for clues to debug the problem.

What are common reasons why page-breaking might stop working in `mdframed`?

Any tricks to try force page-breaking again?

Comment: Use the `framed` package, it breaks across the pages.

Comment: Yep, but in theory, `mdframed` should also break across pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah okay, only a few minutes after asking the question, I found the answer (creating the MWE helped).

The problem was with the `picins` package loaded (I think) in the template class. If you load `picins`, the `mdframed` environments will no longer break over pages, as per this M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{exampl}[section]
\newenvironment{exampl}[1][]{%
 \stepcounter{exampl}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=black!10]
        {\strut Example~\thesection .\theexampl};},nobreak=false}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
     frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=black!10]
        {\strut Example~\thesection .\theexampl:~#1};},nobreak=false}%
   }%
   \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=black!10,nobreak=false,%
             linewidth=2pt,topline=true,backgroundcolor=black!05,%
             frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax}
   \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
   }{\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{exampl}[Lorem ipsum]
   \blindtext

   \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & Table\\
   \end{tabular}

   \Blindtext
\end{exampl}

\end{document}
```

The order of loading the packages doesn't seem to matter either, so either choose page-breaking in `mdframed` or `picins` I guess.

Anyways, sorry for the noise but maybe this will help someone who encounters a similar issue later.

Comment: You should accept your answer, so that your question is not recorded as unanswered.

Comment: Okay, I have to wait two days though according to the system. :)